# Save file dialog in griffon

Tags: java, jfilechooser, griffon

i have a save file dialog in my griffon app. the code is like this:

```
    String filename = siteCode+'-'+model.currentClient.name+'-'+computerName+'-'+date+'.csv'
    File selFile = new File(filename)
    def fc = new JFileChooser()
    fc.setSelectedFile(selFile)
    fc.showSaveDialog()



    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(selFile));
```

The problem is, regardless the path i choose to save file at, it alsways goes to the "Staging" directory in my app's folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you're not reading back the selected file from the dialog but reusing the `selFile` variable? Make sure you call `fc.getSelectedFile()` instead.